# Grammar types constraint after adding a couple of types (and a statement involving them) to a "typeless" language

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars, programming-languages, type-theory, python

*Foreword* : by "typeless programming language", I naively mean "language in which you don't write statements like `type x (=) ...` to declare(define) `x`". Maybe there is an internal typing deduced from what is in `...` but I suppose that this is not the case, as it is not the case in the example interesting me. (If "typeless programming language" already means something, forbid me, but this is not the point.)

Consider the grammar of a "typeless" programming language, python (3.6.3) for instance :

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html

I rather used its description here :

https://github.com/erezsh/plyplus/blob/master/plyplus/grammars/python.g

Then I lightened the grammar *a lot* and modified the resulting subgrammar by adding new features, but for the sake of simplicity, one can assume that I add features to the complete python grammar, not to a subgrammar of it.

Here are my modifications :

1) I added a date "type" (I put type in `""` because there's no type in python)

```
date: US_DATE;
```

where :

```
US_DATE: '!(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[13579][26]|[2468][048])00)|(?:[0-9]{2}(?:(?:[13579][26])|(?:[2468][048]|0[48]))))(?:(?:(?:09|04|06|11)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|30))|(?:(?:01|03|05|07|08|10|12)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01]))|(?:02(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]))))|(?:[0-9]{4}(?:(?:(?:09|04|06|11)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|30))|(?:(?:01|03|05|07|08|10|12)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01]))|(?:02(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-8])))))';
```

(thx to https://stackoverflow.com/a/16088645/1581875)

and I propagated `date` to `atom`.

Then `d = !20171116` produce the following syntax tree :

[image]

2) I also added what I call an `underlying`, and this time it's a real type. Namely, I added a

```
UNDERLYING: 'underlying';
```

in the `%unless` part of `NAME` definition, and I introduced an underlying statement :

```
underlying_stmt : UNDERLYING name (COMMA name)*;
```

that I of course propagated to `small_stmt`.

Now one can write :

```
underlying z
```

which produces the following syntax tree :

[image]

3) Here comes the tricky (at least for me) part : after what preceeds, I introduced a new use of the `@` symbol, namely a "stamp statement", `stamp_stmt`, as follows :

```
stamp_stmt: name AT (name | date);
```

(that I propagated of course to `small_stmt`)

Namely, I can write

```
z @ d #or
z @ !20171116
```

and this will produce the following syntax tree :

[image]

In fact, as I defined the `stamp_stmt`, I can write `name @ date` for any `name` (and `date`).

I cannot write `2 @ !20171116` for instance : this is already a constraint. **I would like to be able, *within the grammar*, to also add the following constraint : `name @ date` could be written only for a `name` of an `underlying`.**

**How could I achieve this ?** I mean, I could still introduce a kind of light "typing" in `name` by refining it by saying that `date` (resp. `underlying`) has `datename` (resp. `underlyingname`) and try to use it to achieve the wanted constraint, but I could also say that `d = !20170823` is not an assignement statement (`assign_stmt`) and introduce a "date assignement statement", same for `underlying`.

Is it anyway a good idea to want to put such a type constraint already in the grammar or not ? (I am really not an expert in languages designing etc ... I am doing all of this because I need a small programming language with the aforementionned features and because around me, no one can help.)

*Remark* : I am doing all of this under windows with [plyplus](https://github.com/erezsh/plyplus) in python and producing syntax trees figures using [graphwiz](http://graphviz.org/).

Comment: So, summing up, you want to allow `name @ date` only when before that we can find `underlying name`. This looks to be the same problem of checking whether a variable was declared before it is used (in languages requiring that). If so, this is usually checked after parsing, since it seems impossible to encode this in the grammar. I'd say you can either 1) do a pass after parsing, or 2) use grammars _with attributes_, and keep track of the "declared" variables during parsing.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to express that constraint with a context-free grammar. (It is, almost by definition, context-sensitive since the validity of `z @ …` depends on the presence of `underlying z`.)

So you are left with two choices:

1. Perform the validity check as a semantic action.
2. Modify the lexical scanner's categorization of tokens on the fly, by recategorizing `z` after `underlying z` is seen.

Option 2 is usually called the "lexical feedback hack" and that is precisely what it is. Sometimes it cannot be conveniently avoided, but this is not one of them.